# MySQL Use Virtual Columns as Join Points?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the three following tables:

monthly:

```
|  u_id   |  memb_type  |  run_day |
------------------------------------
|   1     |       1     |    410   |
|   2     |       1     |    410   |
|   1     |       2     |    510   |
|   2     |       1     |    510   |
|   1     |       2     |    610   |
|   2     |       1     |    610   |
```

memb_types:

```
|    id   |      name      |
----------------------------
|    1    |      member    |
|    2    |  active_member |
```

user:

```
|   id    |   join_date    |
----------------------------
|    1    |    2015-03-01  |
|    2    |    2015-04-04  |
```

The query I'm attempting to write will show what `memb_type` the user was the first two months of them joining. The tricky part is `monthly.run_day` is not a valid datetime, and it basically requires creating multiple virtual columns I have something along the lines of this right now and I'm stuck:

```
SELECT
      user.id,
      user.join_date,
      MONTH(user.join_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AS `first_month`,
      "???" AS `first_month_memb_type`,
      MONTH(user.join_date + INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AS `second_month`,
      "???" AS `second_month_memb_type`
 FROM 
      user
 INNER JOIN
      monthly
 ON 
      user.id = monthly.u_id
 INNER JOIN
      memb_types
 ON
      monthly.memb_type = memb_types.id
```

I'm not exactly sure how to use the data generated from `MONTH(user.join_date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` and join that back to the `monthly` table joined on the `run_day` (`SUBSTRING(monthly.run_day, 1, 1)` Does what we need to match the value from the month to the `run_day`) But I don't know how to join that back to the `monthly` table twice for the `first_month_memb_type` and the `second_month_memb_type`.

Based on the needs the desired output would be as follows (Abbreviated for brevity):

```
| id | join_date  | fm | fm_type | sm |    sm_type    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2015-03-01 | 4  |  member |  5 | active_member |
| 2  | 2015-04-04 | 5  |  member |  6 |    member     |
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Shouldn't the first month just be "month(user.join_date)", and the second month have " + INTERVAL 1 MONTH"?

Comment: Also, is run_day % 100 always 10, or is that just sample data?

Comment: Month is the month after they've joined. And the 10 is usually 10. But safe to say highly variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay to use those functions as the join predicates, which means we just need to join a couple of extra times to get your first and second months all in a row, and only once - instead of two rows per u_id.

```
   select u.id, 
       u.join_date, 
       month(u.join_date + interval 1 month) fm, 
       mt1.name fm_type,
       month(u.join_date + interval 2 month) 2m,
       mt2.name sm_type
  from user u
    inner join monthly m1
      on month(u.join_date + interval 1 month) = substring(m1.run_day, 1, 1)
        and m1.u_id = u.id
    inner join monthly m2
      on month(u.join_date + interval 2 month) = substring(m2.run_day, 1, 1)
        and m2.u_id = u.id
    inner join memb_types mt1
      on m1.memb_type = mt1.id
    inner join memb_types mt2
      on m2.memb_type = mt2.id
```

[demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2264/8)

Note: if your table gets particularly large - it's not going to be much fun joining on the results of functions, in which case you may wish to consider making those 'virtual' columns, not so virtual, and then indexing them.

**edit**
As pointed out in the comments, it may make a slight difference if run_day is a numeric field, to use math rather than substring:

```
select u.id, 
       u.join_date, 
       month(u.join_date + interval 1 month) fm, 
       mt1.name fm_type,
       month(u.join_date + interval 2 month) 2m,
       mt2.name sm_type
  from user u
    inner join monthly m1
      on month(u.join_date + interval 1 month) = floor(m1.run_day / 100)
        and m1.u_id = u.id
    inner join monthly m2
      on month(u.join_date + interval 2 month) = floor(m2.run_day / 100)
        and m2.u_id = u.id
    inner join memb_types mt1
      on m1.memb_type = mt1.id
    inner join memb_types mt2
      on m2.memb_type = mt2.id
```

Comment: If `run_day` is an integer type, the joins might be slightly faster using run_day \ 100 instead of substring.

Comment: thats true - i just ran with what the op had already provided in that respect

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. It is a number field.

Comment: @Peter i threw that version in as well, so long as it is always `MXX`, it should work

Comment: @Peter I was getting my vb knowledge mixed in there with the "\" in the comment; in MySQL it is "DIV" instead (for integer division), and should eliminate the need for the "floor" function call in the join conditions.