# Transform a table horizontally, with filling NULL columns when needed

Tags: join, view, null

I have two tables
ORDERS

```
_____________________
|OrdNum     |Stockid |
----------------------
|1234       |alpha   |  
|1238       |beta    | 
|1745       |gamma   |  
----------------------
```

and MARKS

```
______________________________
|OrdNum     |RowNum|   Mark  |
------------------------------
|1234       |1     |   AB    | 
|1238       |1     |   XY    |    
|1238       |2     |   XZ    |   
|1745       |1     |   KD    |    
|1745       |2     |   KS    |    
|1745       |3     |   JJ    |     
|1745       |4     |   RT    |     
|1745       |5     |   PJ    |   
------------------------------
```

For every order, there can be from 1 up to a maximum of 5 corresponding records in the MARKS table.
I need to do a sort of "Horizontal" join, with NULL values where no corrispondance occurs. Frankly speaking, I am not even sure it can be done.
The final results should look like the following

```
_____________________________________________________
|OrdNum     |Mark1  |Mark2  |Mark3  |Mark4  |Mark5  |
-----------------------------------------------------
|1234       |AB     |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   | 
|1238       |XY     |XZ     |NULL   |NULL   |NULL   |    
|1238       |KD     |KS     |JJ     |RT     |PJ     |   
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Again, the final view has to be horizontal, with 5 (plus order number) columns.
Anybody know if this is possible ?
Thank you in advance.

---

In T-SQL (SQL Server 2008) I did try the following joing 
For the sake of simplification, let us consider only 2 columns instead of 5.

```
SELECT o.OrdNum, 
m1.Mark AS MARK1,
m2.Mark AS MARK2,
FROM ORDERS o 
LEFT JOIN MARKS m1 ON o.OrdNum = m1.OrdNum WHERE m1.RowNum=1
LEFT JOIN MARKS m2 ON o.OrdNum = m2.OrdNum WHERE m2.RowNum=2
```

which is synthetically wrong.
So I modified the join as it follows

```
SELECT o.OrdNum, 
m1.Mark AS MARK1,
m2.Mark AS MARK2,
FROM ORDERS o 
LEFT JOIN MARKS m1 ON o.OrdNum = m1.OrdNum 
LEFT JOIN MARKS m2 ON o.OrdNum = m2.OrdNum 
WHERE m1.RowNum=1 AND m2.RowNum=2
```

which is not what I want to get, since it does not produce the orders having only the record corresponding to the first RowNum (with the values at the beginning of this post, it will not show order number 1234 ..)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979469/mysql-use-virtual-columns-as-join-points  - mark1 (m.Mark or NULL) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Altering a column: null to not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689746/altering-a-column-null-to-not-null)

Comment: dmitryro thanks for hint. However, my need is different. The five joins are based on the same two columns, but need to have a WHERE clause different. As stated in my original question, I do not even know if this is possible. By the way, I am talkinkg about T-SQL